# Work Item Traceability in TFS 2010

Tags: requirements, team-foundation-server, sdlc

I have created a Windows Form project (VS solution) under a TFS 2010 project. I may eventually add more solutions to the TFS project.

**My question**: Can we create a Use Case WIT for a specific solution within a TFS project? Furthermore, is it possible to create a "traceability matrix" that starts at the Use Case level and goes down to the the code level (at least the namespace level) of that particular VS solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used the Agile Process Template, you already have the Use Case. If not, you can [download the Agile process template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181511%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to you local machine and then navigate to the Work Item Types folder and locate the Work Item Type. You can then use the [witadmin importwitd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) command to import it into your team project.

If you already have the work item and you want to scope it down to only your solution, then the [Area Path field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181692.aspx) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, TFS 2010 allows for several different kinds of links between Work Items. Very common is the Parent / Child. Using TFS Out of the Box with the Agile Process Template you can link User Stories to Tasks, and Tasks to Change Sets. Once you find a Bug, you can Link that back to a User Story and once you resolve the Bug, you can associate with a specific change set.

Reporting on this is a little more difficult because I'm not aware of a "traceability matrix" report, but since all the data is in a SQL server, you can query it from SQL Enterprise Manager.